# How do we update column data in rows of similar columns with the data found after merge operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I can find equal column data with concatenation function. But there is something else I want to do.
For example; If the 'customer ID' in the second file has values ​​equal to the customer ID in the first file; I want to save the values ​​in the 'customer rating' column in the same row with equal values ​​in the 'customer rating' column in the row where the 'customer id' column is equal in the first file.

```
 pd.merge(first_file_data,second_file_data,left_on='CUSTOMER ID',right_on='CUSTOMER ID')
```

Output:

Similar customer IDs in the merge transaction:

FİRST FİLE

```
  CUSTOMER ID  CUSTOMER SCORE  
0  3091250      Nan
1  1122522      Nan
```

SECOND_FİLE

```
  CUSTOMER ID  CUSTOMER SCORE
0  3091250      750
1  1122522      890
```

Comment: If I understand you right, do you want to fill NaNs from first dataframe with values from second dataframe?

Comment: yes but I want to do this on rows with the same value I found in the merge function. In other words, if the customer id is '3091250', where the 'customer score' is NaN, the 'customer score' in the row with the customer id '3091250' in the other table should come. Thanks for be interested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `df.fillna()` function. Just set same indexes on `df1` and `df2`:

```
out = df1.set_index('CUSTOMER_ID').fillna(df2.set_index('CUSTOMER_ID')).reset_index()

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   CUSTOMER_ID  CUSTOMER_SCORE
0      3091250           750.0
1      1122522           890.0
```

---

EDIT: To replace NaNs only in one row in df1:

```
df1['CUSTOMER_SCORE'] = df1.set_index('CUSTOMER_ID')['CUSTOMER_SCORE'].fillna(df2.set_index('CUSTOMER_ID')['CUSTOMER_SCORE']).values
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   CUSTOMER_ID  CUSTOMER_SCORE
0      3091250           750.0
1      1122522           890.0
```

Comment: but I just need to update the data in the column without changing the whole row. Because actually in my dataset, besides the customer score and customer ID columns, there are many different columns with different names. sorry for not putting it all

Comment: @sananesanane I've made an edit - how to replace data only in one row.

Comment: Thank you very much for the perspective and information you added. I will research more and work harder.